# Inline-block element gets full width after childs break into new line

Tags: html, css

I recognized, that an inline-block element, gets 100% width if there are more child elements than would fit into one line:

```
<div style="background-color:red;padding:5px">
    <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:green;padding:5px">
        <div class="cube"></div>
        <div class="cube"></div>
        <div class="cube"></div>
        <div class="cube"></div>
        <div class="cube"></div>
        <div class="cube"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
.cube{ 
    background-color:yellow;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xhj075fr/5/

[image]

What i would like to have is a beavior like this:
[image]

Is there a way to get this done with inline block? The goal is, to get a left aligned grid inside of a centered div like this (the width of the green div shoud be based of the number of cubes that fit into one line):

[image]

Comment: Actually that is a really unexpected behaviour. Can anyone explain why it works like this and why it makes sense?

Comment: @connexo, not sure, but since width is not set, width=parent width? (100%, default)?

Comment: I would love to hear what @boltclock has to say about this.

Comment: ..and how much yellow divs should be inside green div...?? max yellow div count in a row i mean?

Comment: @NoobEditor Inside of one row shoud be as many yellow divs as would fit into the red one (dynamic width)(plus margins/paddings). Just like in the fiddle example. The only problem is the width of the green div.

Comment: This is a very common issue. All the width shrink-to-fit elements ( `display:inline-block`, `float:left`, etc) work the same way. taking all the available parent's width if the sum of the widths of the content is greater than the parent width. If the parent width is a function of the browser width, and the cubes are a fixed width, then you can use media queries to set appropriate parent widths, otherwise JavaScript is your only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div style="background-color:red;width:500px;padding:5px">
<div style="margin:auto;width:82.6%;background-color:green;padding:5px">
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
</div>
```

Do come back if the issue not resolved.!

Comment: I bet OP doesn't want to define a width, but wants it to be baase on the number of ccubes that fit into one line.

Comment: yes, the width should be based on the number of cubes that fit into the line

Comment: I bet that there is no solution, except of setting fixed width of sub-container (even container have it, even boxes have it, so why sub-container wouldn't have it?), or using of completely different markup/css, or javascript... So, this answer provide, actually, decent solution.

Comment: I've updated the question and removed the the 500px-width of the parent div, because it was misleading. The main goal is to have a left-aligned grid centered in a dynamic-width parent div